# Python Packages Not Working From Same Directory As Working Packages

Tags: python-3.x, package, google-sheets-api, gspread, oauth2client

I am using Python38.

I am trying to create a script to create/modify google sheets. So I came across several articles detailing how to accomplish this: [article1](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2), [article2](http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/), [article3](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/google-sheets-python-api-tutorial/).

Essentially it boils down to using two python packages: **GSPREAD** and **OAUTH2CLIENT**.

The problem is trying to import either of these returns the **Module Not Found Error**.

Running this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I see the site-packages directory is returned in the list.

I have many other packages installed in the same directory that **do work** (e.g. bs4, Django, Flask, matplotlib, etc, etc), so why are these two packages not being found? Does the PATH variable need to be updated?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

So I failed to mention in the question that I was trying to do the pip install from the command line (cmd on windows). Which successfully installed the packages, but did not allow visibility to the rest of the python environments.

**The way to get this to work was to run the pip install command from the Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda's command line).**